# C# method to read text error log file

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a file I create that contains all the logs lines throughout my program. I have the following cod:

```
    private string ReadEmailLog(string EmailLog)
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(EmailLog);
        tr.ReadLine();
        tr.Close();
    }
```

I need to read the EmailLog file, every line of it, and then put return it into a string called message. How would I get this method to return the whole log file, every line?

Comment: also the error log contains different lines of text which I would like to keep as seperate lines.

Comment: is the `EmailLog` string a path to a file, or the actual log?

Comment: it is the file name. "LogFile"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) or [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

If you're using .NET 4.0, you can also use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx):

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\",
                "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            where line.Contains("Microsoft")
            select new
            {
                File = file,
                Line = line
            };

foreach (var f in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
}
```

This allows you to make file I/O part of a LINQ operation.

Comment: @Will: glad to help. I recommend taking a quick scan of all the `File` methods. There's some nice stuff there for quick file I/O tasks.

Comment: @user: are you using .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tr.ReadToEnd();
```

which will return a string that contains all the content of your file.
[TextReader.ReadToEnd Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readtoend.aspx)

If you want to get the lines in a `string[]`, then

```
tr.ReadToEnd().Split("\n");
```

should do it, while it will separate the lines to the "\n" character, which represents a carriage return and line feed combined characters (new line character).

Comment: I prefer the `File` versions, as there's no issue with forgetting to implement `using` blocks.

Comment: The OP is already not using `using` block, though it would be strongly recommended. Besides, I didn't know or never noticed about the `File` versions. Thanks for this hint! =)

Comment: this is why I prefer the `File` versions - not possible to forget the `using` block, or rather, you can forget it, with no harm.`

Answer (score 1):

simply use:

```
    String text = tr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the contents or the log and return it. For example:

```
private string void ReadEmailLog(string EmailLog)
{
    using(StreamReader logreader = new StreamReader(EmailLog))
    {
        return logreader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Or if you want each line one at a time:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ReadEmailLogLines(string EmailLog)
{
    using(StreamReader logreader = new StreamReader(EmailLog))
    {
        string line = logreader.ReadLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
             yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the first part gives me what I want but I want carriage returns between all the lines that have carriage returns?

Comment: the first part (i.e `ReadToEnd()`) will give you exactly what ever is in the file, so if there are carriage returns then they will be there.

Answer (score -1):

```
tr.ReadToEnd(); //read whole file at once

// or line by line

While ( ! tr.EOF)
tr.ReadLine()//
```

Comment: -1: `TextReader.Read` reads a single character, so your example doesn't show how to do it line by line.

Comment: i'm sorry i meant tr.ReadLine()